# How can I get a certain range of string input?

Tags: java, string

I want to know if it's possible to get a range of input from a string.

Let's say the input is a string that says `"(INPUT:the dog, the cat)"`.
How can we snip the string from the `:` to the `,`? Is this possible ?

Comment: See the `substring()` and `indexOf` methods of `String` class.

Comment: Or use a regex that captures everything between ":" and ",".

Comment: You've gotto show us exact inputs and expected outputs.. The 2 comments mentioned above are actually answers :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `String::substring()` method to get a portion of a string from the actual string.

> `substring()` method takes either start index or both start index and end index and returns a string between those indexes.

```
String s = "(INPUT:the dog, the cat)";
System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf(":") + 1, s.indexOf(",")));//the dog
```

If you want all the other inputs too, You could combine it with split()

```
String s = "(INPUT:the dog, the cat)";
String inp = s.substring(s.indexOf(":") + 1, s.length() - 1);
String []tokens = inp.split(", ");//["the dog", "the cat"]
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i)
    System.out.println(tokens[i]);
```

Comment: Good answer. But in the future, try to avoid providing full solution for questions that don't demonstrate minimal efforts. This way, OP is not really having good learning process because they rely on your solution and might use it without understanding it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Noted :)

Answer (score 2):

In Java Strings are objects, so, every String has methods to manipulate with String contents.

For your task there are two useful methods.

[indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) - Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character.

[substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) - Returns a string that is a substring of this string.

There are several methods with the same name but different signatures (parameters), so choose according to your particular needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SnipString {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = "(INPUT:the dog, the cat)";
        String str1 = "";
        char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == ':') {
                i++;
                while (arr[i] != ',') {
                    str1 = str1 + arr[i];
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(str1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reason for rebuilding core features? Or for not explaining what you're doing there? OP wasn't even able to use google to find an answer for his task, so he may also have problems understanding your answer.